# Troubles with Inheritance in java

Tags: java, inheritance

I got a really simple question about inheritance in java.
The code might not seem very compelling, but it has to do with the basics
of inheritance and I just don't see the problem why the code should not work at all.
Here is the code:

```
class Lizard {}  

class Iguana extends Lizard {} 

class TestDriver {
   public static void main(String[] args) { 
      Iguana iguana1 = new Iguana();
      Lizard lizard1 = new Lizard();
      Lizard lizard2 = iguana1;

  } 
}
```

I know that I need to use a cast..but where? And why doesn't the code compile?

In my view it seems to work out having a "lizard" object referencing an "iguana"(last line).
I hope someone can help me! :)

Comment: No cast is needed and the code should compile and run with no problems.

Comment: Are each of these classes in different files? And in the same package?

Comment: If it doesn't compile, post the error. Don't let people guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use a cast because an Iguana is a subclass of Lizard.  So if the compiler sees an Iguana it *knows* that it can be considered to be a Lizard.

If you go the other way -- attempt to assign a Lizard reference to an Iguana -- then the actual object may be an Iguana, or it may instead be some other sort of Lizard, so you need to use the cast to tell the compiler "I know what I'm doing and this *really is* an Iguana."

Comment: @Lilly If this or any other answer satisfactorily solves your problem, you should accept it by clicking the checkmark next to it. The same applies to any other question you may ask in the future. You even get two reputation points! If you want more information, you can look at this Meta post: [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/238586).

Comment: Got it! 
Do you know why I get a classCastException when I try to use "Iguana iguana = (Iguana) lizard1" ? Since iguana "is a" lizard it should be perfectly valid to add a cast as you suggested

Comment: @Lilly -- You get ClassCastException if, eg, you try to cast an object that *really is* a Lizard to Iguana.  Understand there's a difference between the type of the reference value and the actual type of the object referenced.  Cast does not change the type of *object* that you have.  (Understanding the difference between an object and the pointer/reference to the object is critical to understanding object-oriented programming.)

Comment: @HotLicks Thanks, now it makes sense..! I still need time to understand the crucial point of OOP

Answer (score 5):

> I know that I need to use a cast..but where?

No, in this case you don't need any cast.

```
Iguana iguana1 = new Iguana();  // Ok: Iguana can be assigned to Iguana
Lizard lizard1 = new Lizard();  // Ok: Lizard can be assigned to Lizard
Lizard lizard2 = iguana1;       // Ok since an Iguana *is a* Lizard
```

> And why doesn't the code compile?

It *does* compile. I just checked myself.

Comment: it doesn't compile with eclipse..but never mind I got it now

Comment: Eclipse is what I used. What error message do you get?